# insert two figures in latex without space between them?

Tags: spacing, graphics

[image]

I'm using this code

```
\begin{table}

  \caption{Variables considered in reviewed papers}

  \label{tbl:table2}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Literature Table 1.PNG}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Literature Table 2.PNG}
\end{table}
```

but there is space between the figures. How can I make the two pictures look like one figure

Comment: depends on whether space is there around the original picture of the table

Comment: Put a `%` after `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Literature Table 1.PNG}`, that is `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Literature Table 1.PNG}%`